# Meaning of $ E(u|v) = p\,v$

Tags: self-learning, conditional-expectation

I am having problem understanding the intuition behind this: if $u$ and $v$ are jointly normal (with zero mean), then $E(u|v) = p\,v$, for some parameter $p$ ?

Answer (score 0):

It means that $u$ and $v$ aren't independent, and they have a *covariance* of $p$. For instance, if you know from the context that $u = -v$ always holds, then $u$ and $v$ have a covariance of $-1$, and the fact that $E(u \mid v) = -v$ should be quite apparent.

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Comment: @Navi I did. In case you missed it, my example was $u = -v$, which gives a covariance of $p = -1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u$ and $v$ are jointly normal  each with a zero mean and correlation $\rho$, where $|\rho|<1$, that is,
\begin{align*}
\rho =\frac{E(uv)}{\sqrt{E(u^2)}\sqrt{E(v^2)}}.
\end{align*}
Then $v$ and 
\begin{align*}
X := \frac{u}{\sqrt{E(u^2)}}-\rho\frac{v}{\sqrt{E(v^2)}}
\end{align*} 
are independent normal random variables (for two jointly normal random variable, if the covariance is zero, then they are independent). Therefore,
\begin{align*}
E(u\mid v) &= E\left(\sqrt{E(u^2)}X + \rho\frac{\sqrt{E(u^2)}}{\sqrt{E(v^2)}}v \mid v \right)\\
&= E\left(\sqrt{E(u^2)}X \mid v \right) + \rho\frac{\sqrt{E(u^2)}}{\sqrt{E(v^2)}} v \\
&= \sqrt{E(u^2)}E(X) + \rho\frac{\sqrt{E(u^2)}}{\sqrt{E(v^2)}}v \\
&= pv,
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
p = \rho\frac{\sqrt{E(u^2)}}{\sqrt{E(v^2)}}.
\end{align*}

Comment: What is X and from where is this term under the square root? Why in the last expression is only pv?

Comment: @Navi: see the beginning for the definitionm of $X$. Moreover, $X$ have mean zero as $u$ and $v$ do.

Comment: @Navi: revised.

Comment: I am all confused with this expectation notation. Is there any document where I could see this in simple terms to get the general idea behind this? I appreciate your effort, but I need to learn some basics before I could understand this.

Comment: @Navi: In that case, you do need to read some probaility books, in particular, regarding normal random varaibles. The book "Probability"  by Shiryaev is a good one.

Comment: Is there any particular chapter of the book dealing with this topic because I noticed they can be obtained separately?

Comment: @Navi: I can not remember. You may use the index for help.

Comment: Just to make sure - are we talking about this book: https://www.amazon.com/Probability-Graduate-Texts-Mathematics-v/dp/0387945490 ?

Comment: @Navi: yes, it is.

Comment: Is E(X)=0 and why?

Comment: @Navi: Since $E(u)=E(v)=0$, and $X$ is a linear combination of $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Does this mean that if we sum ∑X across all values of ∑u and  ∑v and then dividing it by the total number of combinations of (u, v) which is equal to N1*N2, we would get zero because ∑u/N1 = 0 and ∑v/N2 = 0? Am I on the right track? How to express this mathematically?

Comment: @Navi: I do not understand this. Note that normal random variable is continuous not discrete. It appears that you really need to go through that book.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that the example I provided is for discrete variable. I just wanted to check if I understood the rationale correctly.

Comment: If X=Z-W, then E(X)=E(Z)-E(W), and since in the nominator of both Z and W we have E(u) and E(v), then E(X)=0?

Comment: I've been doing some reading and some thing are much clearer now. However, could you please provide how covariance between X and v equals 0?

Comment: My gues would be: Cov(X, v) = E(Xv)-E(X)*E(v)=E(X)*E(v)-E(X)*E(v); since E(v)=0 Cov(X,v)=0. Is this correct?

Comment: Comments are getting too long. Please ask as another question.

Comment: I understand. I asked new question.

Comment: Why we use linear transformations like the one from your solution?

Comment: @Navi: we assume that, for certain $a$ and $b$, $au+bv$ and $v$ are independent, and then try to find a particular form for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: So basically the underlying logic is the same as with equation with unknowns where we find their value based on known variables. Are there any particular formulae for deriving $a$ and $b$??

Comment: @Navi: try what does independence mean

Comment: It means that covariance of two random variables is zero.