# Which of the following is true for random variables $X$ and $Y$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables such that $aX+bY$ is a normal random
>   variable for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.
>
> Consider the following statements P, Q, R and S:
>
> (P) : $X$ is a standard normal random variable.
>
> (Q) : The conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y$ is normal.
>
> (R) : The conditional distribution of $X$ given $X+Y$ is normal.
>
> (S) : $X-Y$ has mean $0$.
>
> Then which of the above statements are true?

I have no idea how to approach this problem. Please help me to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: For (P) there's no reason $X$ should be "standard" normal.  Same with (S) there' no reason $X-Y$ need to have mean zero.

Comment: $X-Y$ is a normal r.v so its mean is not zero so (S) is false. Now how to so Q and R are true or not?

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian How characteristic function will help me?

Comment: Well $X$ is normal and $Y$ is normal (take $a=1,b=0$ and $a=0,b=1$).  So $(X,Y)$ is bivariate normal.  So the conditional $X|Y$ is normal.  Same for $X$ given $X+Y$  So Q and R are true, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your assumption, $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal. Let $\rho$ be the correlation, that is,
\begin{align*}
\rho = \frac{E\big((X-E(X))(Y-E(Y)) \big)}{\sqrt{E\left((X-E(X))^2 \right)}\sqrt{E\left((Y-E(Y))^2 \right)}}.
\end{align*}
Then, $Y-E(Y)$ and
\begin{align*}
Z:=\frac{X-E(X)}{\sqrt{E\left((X-E(X))^2 \right)}} -\rho \frac{Y-E(Y)}{\sqrt{E\left((Y-E(Y))^2 \right)}}
\end{align*}
are independent, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1847760/meaning-of-euv-p-v/1848663#1848663) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1852467/testing-the-independence-of-two-jointly-normal-variables). Therefore,
\begin{align*}
E(X\mid Y) &= E\left(\sqrt{E\left((X-E(X))^2 \right)}\, Z + E(X) + \rho\, (Y-E(Y))\frac{\sqrt{E\left((X-E(X))^2 \right)}}{\sqrt{E\left((Y-E(Y))^2 \right)}} \mid Y \right)\\
&= E(X) + \rho\, (Y-E(Y))\frac{\sqrt{E\left((X-E(X))^2 \right)}}{\sqrt{E\left((Y-E(Y))^2 \right)}},
\end{align*}
which is normal.

Similarly, since $X$ and $X+Y$ are also jointly normal,
\begin{align*}
E(X \mid X+Y) 
\end{align*}
is normal.